# Highlight selector does not appear on Linkified ListViewItem's

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem, linkify

When I use Linkify in my ListViewItem the highlight selector seems to go off and only the text gets highlighted.

```
Linkify.addLinks(bodyTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

How can I get the highlight selector back when I click on a ListViewItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you have other elements that focus inside your ListView items, in this case, the linkified text, then you loose the ability to focus on the actual list item. As far as I know. Same thing happens once you add buttons or checkboxes inside.

See [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg11390.html) message post by Romain Guy on a similar topic.